# How to properly control cascading deletion in EF Core using Fluent API?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I have two entities, *Tag* and *Member*. A member can be marked with multiple tags. A tag can be used to mark multiple members. It's a clear case of many-to-many relation and since I'm using EF Core, I have to declare an explicit connector, which I call *Tag_Member*. I configure it in the following way.

```
private void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Tag_Member> entity)
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.TagId, e.MemberId });
  entity.HasOne(e => e.Tag);
  entity.HasOne(e => e.Member)
    .WithMany(e => e.Tag_Member)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.MemberId);
}
```

The behavior I wish to enforce when deleting is as follows.

- When removing an instance of *Tag_Member*, nothing is changed.
- When removing an instance of *Tag*, any connected instances of *Tag_Member* are deleted.
- When removing an instance of *Member*, any connected instances of *Tag_Member* are deleted.

I'm confused on two points. When I add the condition for deletion as shown below, I have a lot of options to pick from and, despite reading the intellisense, I don't feel certain which to use to enforce the above behavior.

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.Member)
  .WithMany(e => e.Tag_Member)
  .HasForeignKey(e => e.MemberId)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

Should I use *NoAction*, *ClientNoAction*, *Restrict* or someting else? I'm not even clear on which of hte entities that the deletetion behavior affects. Which is it?

The second point of confusion is that I don't get *OnDelete()* to appear for the tag configuration. I haven't used *WithMany()* because that entity lacks references back to the interlinking entity. Can I still manage its deletion behavior? Do I need to explicitly declare it to achieve the requested behavior?

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.Tag)
  .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
```

The classes look roughly like this.

```
public class Tag { public Guid Id { get; set; } }
public class Member { public Guid Id { get; set; } }

public class Tag_Member
{
  public Guid TagId { get; set; }
  public Guid MemberId { get; set; }
  public Tag Tag { get; set; }
  public Member Member { get; set; }
}
```

My references are mainly [this](https://entityframeworkcore.com/saving-data-cascade-delete) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/cascade-delete).

**edit:** Based on the suggestions in the answer, this is the final version of the relation between members and tag.

```
private static void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Member> entity)
{
  entity.HasKey(e => e.Id); ...
}

private static void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Tag> entity)
{
  entity.HasKey(e => e.Id); ...
}

private static void OnModelCreating(EntityTypeBuilder<Member_Tag> entity)
{
  entity.HasKey(e => new { e.MemberId, e.TagId });
  entity.HasOne(e => e.Member).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
  entity.HasOne(e => e.Tag).WithMany().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm not even clear on which of hte entities that the deletetion behavior affects. Which is it?

That's easy. The cascade delete always affects the *dependent* entity (i.e. the entity containing the FK).

> I don't feel certain which to use to enforce the above behavior. Should I use `NoAction`, `ClientNoAction`, `Restrict` or someting else?

You seem to be using EF Core 3.0 preview which adds more options not documented yet. But the option for *classic* cascade delete implemented at the database level  has always been `Cascade`.

> I haven't used `WithMany()` because that entity lacks references back to the interlinking entity.

In order to be able to fluently configure the relationship aspects, you have to fully specify the relationship parties by using the `Has` + `With` pair. Since *navigation properties* are not mandatory for either side of the relationship, all you need it to pass the correct argument to `Has` / `With` method - if you do have navigation property, pass the name or lambda expression accessor, otherwise don't pass anything (but still include the call). e.g.

```
entity.HasOne(e => e.Tag)
    .WithMany() // <--
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // now you can do this
```

But note that `DeleteBehavior.Cascade` is the *default* for *required* relationships (in other words, when the FK is non nullable type), so you normally don't need fluent configuration for that. And if the property names follow the EF Core naming conventions, you don't need fluent configuration at all.

Simple example can be seen [here](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-ef-core.aspx).

Comment: I get the idea in the 1-to-many case but in many-to-many, I somehow fail to grasp it. I want to cascade a deletion but only one way and only half-way through. Meaning - if I remove a tag, I want all the tag-member instances gone. But I want the linked members to stay. Also if I remove a tag-member instance, I want it not to cascade anything. So I want do cascade deletion from tag to tag-member but not to member itself. And I want not to cascade anything from tag-member to tag. (Correspondingly from member to tag of course.) Should I declare cascading three times (for tag, member, tag-member)?

Comment: Should I declare cascading three times (for tag, member, tag-member)? I was told to only configure the relations between X and Y at one place (either configuring X or configuring Y). But perhaps that person was mistaken. What do you think?

Comment: See the first part of the answer. Cascade always work from principal to dependant. Many-to-many relationship is simple 2 one-to-many relationship, `Tag` and `Member` are principals, and the join entity is dependent of both relatioships. So cascade works exactly the way you want - deleting `Tag` or `Member` deletes the related links, but not the "other" object from the link.

Comment: Each relationship includes 2 entities, but it's still 1 relationship, so it has to be configured once. `a.HasMany(a => a.Bs).WithOne(b => b.A)` is exactly the same as `b.HasOne(b => b.A).WithMany(a => a.Bs)` and both represent *one and the same relationship*. So no, you need only 2 fluent configurations because you have 2 relationships.

Comment: Sorry for being dense. I think I start to grasp it, thanks to you explanation. Would you throw an eye at the edit where I show the final setup for the entities? I moved the configuration of the two relations to the method that manages the middle man. It makes most sense and appears to be clean. I also set the cascading to *NoAction* in both ends because deleting the middle instance should never affect the linked ones.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, it doesn't matter in which method you configure the relationship, because there are 2 "mans", but only 1 (shared) relationship. So what you did is *not* ok. (1) The cascading  should be `Cascade` because you are configuring what happens when you delete the "main man". (2)  `.WithMany()` will cause problems if you have collection navigation properties in the main mans as it seems from the initial code. Make sure you use `.WithMany(e => e.Tag_Member)` instead.

Comment: (3) as mentioned at the end of the answer, the behavior you are looking for is the *default*,  so simply *remove* the 2 lines starting with `entity.HasOne`. The only configuration needed is the composite primary key.

Comment: All this along with the terminology and examples is explained in EF Core [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) documentation topic.

Comment: Now I got it. I pasted in a link to an example that help complete the picture. Thanks for your patience, mate.